# Isomorphic group on the set $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can someone tell me if I am using correct knowledge to find an isomorphism?

I need to find an isomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $G$, where $G$ is the set of real numbers with the following operation: $x * y=x+y+1$.

let $f(x) = x-1$, then $f(x+y) = x+y-1$ and

$f(x) * f(y) = (x-1) * (y-1) = (x-1)+(y-1)+1 = x+y-1$

Since $f(x+y) = f(x)*f(y)$ and $f(x) = x-1$ is bijective then $f(x) = x-1$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $G$.

Comment: you are all correct.